# extract object by property prefix

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I tried to loop through a huge list of properties in object, but failed to extract properties that has the same prefix, I can't use object `delete`function because the list is huge, where is my mistake?

```
const a = {
  obj_abc: true,
  obj_def: false,
  hello_123: true,
  hello_456: 'another value'
};

let b = {};

for(k in a){
    const [key] = k.split('_');
    if(key === 'hello') {
      b = {...b[key], [key]:a[k]} //the problem is here, it gave me only hello_456: 'another value'

    }
}

console.log(b);
```

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using bracket notation

```js
const a = {
  obj_abc: true,
  obj_def: false,
  hello_123: true,
  hello_456: 'another value'
};

let b = {};

for (k in a) {
  const [key] = k.split('_');
  if (key === 'hello') {
    b[k] = a[k];
  }
}

console.log(b);
```

Using [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```js
const a = {
  obj_abc: true,
  obj_def: false,
  hello_123: true,
  hello_456: 'another value'
};

let b = {};

for (k in a) {
  if (k.startsWith('hello_')) {
    b[k] = a[k];
  }
}

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `key` is `hello` for both `hello_123` and `hello_456`, hence its overriding the old entry for `hello` key. you need unique keys. eg below.

```js
const a = {
  obj_abc: true,
  obj_def: false,
  hello_123: true,
  hello_456: 'another value'
};

let b = {};

for(k in a){
    const [key] = k.split('_');
    if(key === 'hello') {
    //key is hello for both hello_123 and hello_456, hence its overriding
      b[k] = a[k] //the problem is here, it gave me only hello_456: 'another value'

    }
}

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const a = {
  obj_abc: 123,
  obj_def: 456,
  hello_123: 123,
  hello_456: 456
};

// filter out the keys that start with hello
var keys = Object.keys(a).filter(function(k) {
  return k.indexOf("hello") === 0;
});

//to convert an array of filtered keys into an object of key-value pairs
var res = keys.reduce(function(matched, k) {
  matched[k] = a[k];
  return matched;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use entries, reduce for clean code. Same time you can create map of all key, later good to extract. See the example 2.

```js
// Example 1
const a = {
    obj_abc: true,
    obj_def: false,
    hello_123: true,
    hello_456: 'another value'
};

const result = Object.entries(a).reduce((map, [key, value]) => {
    if (key.indexOf("hello_") === 0) map[key] = value
    return map
}, {})

console.log(result);

// To collect all in once
// Example 2
const result2 = Object.entries(a).reduce((map, [key, value]) => {
    const [k] = key.split("_")
    if(!map[k]) map[k] = {}
    map[k][key] = value
    return map
}, {})

console.log(result2); // { obj: { obj_abc: true, obj_def: false }, hello: { hello_123: true, hello_456: 'another value' } }
console.log(result2["hello"]); // { hello_123: true, hello_456: 'another value' }
console.log(result2["obj"]); // { obj_abc: true, obj_def: false }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find my answer.

```js
const a = {
  obj_abc: true,
  obj_def: false,
  hello_123: true,
  hello_456: "another value"
};

let b = {};

for (key in a) {
  let [text] = key.split("_");

  if (!(text in b)) {
    b[text] = { [key]: a[key] };
  }
 else {
    Object.assign(b[text], { [key]: a[key] });
  }
}

console.log(b);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
  "obj": {
    "obj_abc": true,
    "obj_def": false
  },
  "hello": {
    "hello_123": true,
    "hello_456": "another value"
  }
}
```